# Indicator random variable of a set. Intuition

Tags: probability, random-variables

Can someone explain me the intuition of the following problem? 
Consider $X$ and $Y$ that are indicator random variables for the events $A$ and $B$ respectively. $$A \,\text{and} \,B$$ are independent events iff $$X\, \text{and} \,Y$$ are independent random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is the indicator for set $A$, you can write $X$ as  $$X(ω)=\begin{cases}1, & ω\in A,\\ 0, & ω\notin A\end{cases}$$ for any $ω \in Ω$. Similarly for $Y$. A common way to write $X$ is $X(ω)=\mathbf 1_{ω\inΑ}$. Now  $$P(A)=P(\{ω\in Ω: ω\in A \})=P(\{ω\in Ω:X(ω)=1\})=P(X=1)$$ and similarly $P(B)=P(Y=1)$. Moreover \begin{align}P(A\cap B)&=P(\{ω\in Ω: ω\in A \text{ and } ω\in B\})\\[0.2cm]&=P(\{ω\in Ω:X(ω)=1\text{ and }Y(ω)=1\})=P(X=1,Y=1)\end{align}  Combine this to obtain that $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B) \iff P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$$